# VS 2019 Publish issue - Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Tags: visual-studio-2019, publish

I am having an issue when I try to publish a specific solution.

Related into:

1. I have been able to publish/deploy about 6 solutions with no issues.
2. The solution that is giving me issues when I try to Publish runs 100% on my local VS 2019, the issue is publishing
3. This is my first solution I created from new on VS 2019. All others were created on VS 2017
4. I can run in browser - https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
5. I did try to Run a NuGet package restore
6. I did try to implement different solutions I found while researching

If you google search for the error of “The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel” you will see a lot of articles. I tried the solutions detailed with obviously no luck.

...

```
1>------ Publish started: Project: HFSPackagesApi, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to C:\deployments\HFSPackagesApi...
Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(128,5): Error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'F:\source\BitBucket\gmborl\LiveBackup\ReleaseInsightApp\HFSPackagesApi\HFSPackagesApi\obj\publish\win-x64\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

1>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it in Windows 7 by doing these steps, outlined in [Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi):

#### Step 1

Add a `DWORD` registry entry called `DefaultSecureProtocols` with a value of `0x00000a00` to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp
```

Note: Second one (in `Wow6432Node`) is needed only on 64-bit Windows.

#### Step 2

Created sub keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
```

In each of them add a `DWORD` entry called `DisabledByDefault` with a value of `0`.

Note: You may need to create the `TLS 1.x` key and also the `Client` key.

Answer (score 0):

After getting my Window 10 laptop operational with VS 2019 I am able to publish my solution.

This is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The OS is windows 7 profession service pack 1. When I published the ASP NET CORE project on IIS, the problem happened.
I solved it with the following steps.

First, I searched the https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json on browser, it worked.
Second, I followed the solution from user11693, and I solved it.